# Openshift cronjob for active directory

Tags: python, cron, azure-active-directory, openshift

I want to create an openshift cronjob to validate a specific pattern of AD groups in azure and populate them in OCP groups/

I created a python script to check the pattern

```
import re
import os


ad_groups = os.environ.get('AD_GROUPS')
def is_valid_ad_group(ad_group_name):
    pattern = #pattern 1 
    
    pattern2 = #pattern2
    if re.match(pattern, ad_group_name, re.IGNORECASE) or re.match(pattern2, ad_group_name, re.IGNORECASE):
        print("Pattern matched")
        return True
    else:
        print("Pattern unmatched")
        return False
        
test_cases = ad_groups.split(',') if ad_groups else []

for test_case in test_cases:
    print(f"Input: {test_case}")
    result = is_valid_ad_group(test_case)
```

any idea what next steps could be

Answer (score 0):

How about continuing to write the script to populate them in OCP groups using the OpenShift CLI (i.e. `oc adm groups new <group-name>`)? Then, deploy a CronJob to run the script. You can refer to https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html for more information on CronJobs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Azure AD Connect*1, you can use LDAP Group Sync feature in OpenShift*2

The LDAP Group Sync feature has a filter using whitelist or blacklist.

*1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/architecture/sync-ldap

*2: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.13/authentication/ldap-syncing.html#ldap-syncing-activedir_ldap-syncing-groups